# Can blocks/methods be interchangeable?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I'm coming from C#/Java/JS to objectiveC and I'm only a couple of days in, so go easy on me.

...so I have a method that takes a block as a parameter:

```
-(void)subToPub: (NSString*)publisherName 
      channelId: (NSString*)channelId 
       callback: (void(^)(NSDictionary*))cb
```

which I would usually use as follows:

```
[myObj  subToPub:@"someId" 
       channelId:@"someOtherId" 
        callback:[(^(NSDictionary* msg){
                    NSLog(@"cb2: %@",msg);
                 }) copy]
];
```

Now, say I have another method with a compatible signature, for instance:

```
-(void)subscribeHandler:(NSDictionary*)msg{
    NSLog(@"cb2: %@",msg);
}
```

is it possible to pass this in as the callback to the subToPub method above, or do I need to wrap this method call in a block?

Comment: This is an excellent question - C# compiler lets you pass a method name into a function expecting a delegate. I don't think Objective C lets you do it, though. I'm curious to find out an answer (writing a small block and calling methods from it does not count :)

Comment: Yes, mainly because writing the unsubscribe method requires a reference to that block, so I need to keep hold of it for the duration of the subscription. Wrapping doesn't help me here.

Comment: I want to note that you shouldn't have to copy the block you pass as an argument -- that method takes a block type parameter, it is responsible for proper memory management.

Comment: @newacct: I think that because I have ARC turned on, weird sh*t happens with blocks when they fall out of scope. If I don't copy, I crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: @newacct See "How do blocks work in ARC?" in this doc: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: @spender: No, that *method* is responsible for copying (if it needs to store it around). The caller shouldn't have to know or assume anything.

Comment: @newacct... that makes a lot of sense... Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logically you need three pieces of information to make a call to the selector described. The object instance, the name of the selector and the dictionary parameter.

The block you pass accepts only one piece of information when called — the dictionary. Everything else needs to be captured within the block.

So, logically, the selector can't be a straight substitution for the block. Besides anything else, where does knowledge of which instance to call it on come from?

The only way to produce a record of 'this method on this specific object' and compact that into a single object is to put it into a block.

If you have a defined format of method you want to call (in this case, one with a single argument) and know the object implicitly then you might consider passing in a selector (`SEL`). So e.g.

```
[myObj  subToPub:@"someId" 
       channelId:@"someOtherId" 
        callback:@selector(subscribeHandler:)
];
```

... and subsequently, assuming you know the object you want to talk to as `obj` and have stored the `SEL` you received as `selector`:

```
[obj performSelector:selector withObject:msg];
```

If you want to pass more than one argument then you need to start fooling about with `NSInvocation`s; it's quite ugly and you'll soon start to appreciate why closures were added to the language.

Comment: Nice answer @Tommy. I'll go with this.

Comment: BTW, I had no idea that closures were a late arrival. I think I'd be suffering much pain without them.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this

```
[myObj  subToPub:@"someId" 
       channelId:@"someOtherId" 
        callback:[(^(NSDictionary* msg){
                    [object subscribeHandler:msg];
                 }) copy]
];
```

Comment: Yep, wrap it. That's a shame.

Comment: block is totally different to method, so I don't think there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap it. Clearly you know how to do that, e.g. ^(void)subscribeHandler:@[@"key": @"value"].